# Xcode: objective-c и swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c

подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в проекте Xcode который разрабатывается на языке Swift подключить функционал написанный на objective-c с другого проекта. То есть, необходимо из проекта с Objective-c который представляет из себя "одностраничное приложение" импортировать ui и код в проект с Swift, и использовать эту "страницу" но уже совместно с другими "окнами" напитанными на swift. Извините если выражаюсь не очень грамотно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно. Swift совместим с Objective-C и можно использовать из одного языка другой и наоборот.